# How do I make endfloats and appendix table numbering work together

Tags: appendices, appendix, renewcommand, endfloat

I am trying to make LaTeX do two things, both of which work in isolation, but not together.

My desired result is a main text followed by bibliography and all tables and figures numbered normally, followed by some appendices, an appendix biblio, and all the appendix figures and tables numbered A.1 A.2 etc. AND IT WORKS, except that in the appendix the markers for [Figure A.2 about here] are instead numbered in the same sequence as the main text. e.g. here
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}

% \usepackage{beamerthemesplit} // Activate for custom appearance
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.1in, right=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{SM}{Appendix References}
%\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{pbox}


\usepackage[toc, title]{appendix}

\title{The Ant and the Grasshopper: \\ Seasonality and the Invention of Agriculture}
\author{
\\ Author
} 


\date{\today}
\vspace{1cm}


\begin{document}


Table \ref{Table1}  does just fine

 \begin{table}[H] 
 \hspace*{-1.5cm}
\centering
 \scalebox{0.70}{%
    \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{\ignorespaces}{\unskip}%
     \begin{tabular}{c c}
    2 & 2
    \end{tabular}
    \unskip
}
\caption{This table is fine in all respects }\label{Table1} 
\end{table}


\newpage

\bibliographystyle{ecta}

\bibliography{naturebib} 

 \processdelayedfloats 

\appendix

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
 \setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}




\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\section{Econometric robustness}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

%\subsection{Econometric robustness}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}




\subsection{Appendix subsection}
Table \ref{DistanceDateAdop} should be the same in this sentence and for the marker below.


\begin{table}
\scalebox{0.75}{%
    \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{\ignorespaces}{\unskip}%
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
    2 & 2
    \end{tabular}
    \unskip}
\caption{This table is titled fine} \label{DistanceDateAdop} 
\end{table}





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

endfloat introduces a new counter, so you need to redefine that; see `\renewcommand{\theposttable}{A\arabic{posttable}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}


\usepackage[toc, title]{appendix}

\title{The Ant and the Grasshopper: \\ Seasonality and the Invention of Agriculture}
\author{
\\ Author
} 


\date{\today}
\vspace{1cm}


\begin{document}


Table \ref{Table1}  does just fine

 \begin{table}[H] 
t
\caption{This table is fine in all respects }\label{Table1} 
\end{table}


\newpage




\appendix

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\theposttable}{A\arabic{posttable}}
 \setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}



\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\section{Econometric robustness}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

%\subsection{Econometric robustness}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}


\processdelayedfloats


\subsection{Appendix subsection}
Table \ref{DistanceDateAdop} should be the same in this sentence and for the marker below.


\begin{table}
t1a 
\caption{This table is titled fine \label{DistanceDateAdop} }
\end{table}






\end{document}
```